# Fast/Efficient way to determine closest location from collection

Tags: ios, swift, sqlite, core-data, cllocation

I am thinking about how to structure the data within my app and one of the most important lookups will be closest location from a collection of location (10,000+ locations) and I'm looking for the fastest and most efficient way to do this.

Ideas I have:

1. Use Core Data and store cllocations or doubles, query with a predicate to order by closest to reference location
2. Store them in an sqlite database and use the distance formula in sql query
3. Load all locations into memory into some sort of a data structure (array, linked list, hashmap, etc.) and compute the distance a different way

Of these solustions, which would be the fastest/most efficient? Or is there another solution you would recommend?

Comment: Check if SQLite RTree could help: https://sqlite.org/rtree.html

Comment: This is a tradeoff between speed and memory usage; which is more efficient depends on your environment.

Comment: With CoreData and a SQLite backing store, it is not possible to sort a fetchRequest using a computed value, so your (1) is going to be difficult.  You could use a predicate to filter your data to those within a given box or radius, and then sort in memory to get the nearest.

Comment: @pbasdf - If using SQLite directly, you can sort using a computed value, by implementing a custom function. I'd assume its going to be much slower than loading the whole array into memory and sorting it there, but you certainly can do it. But, if he's really only interested in the nearest matches, then sort might not be the best approach, anyway, as that has time complexity of something along the lines of O(n log n), whereas finding the nearest is really a O(n) problem.

Comment: @Rob - I guessed it might be possible using SQLite directly, but have no experience of it myself, so thanks for clarifying.  Good point about finding nearest v sorting: that does open some avenues for achieving it in a CoreData fetch.  But I suspect you are right: doing it in memory will be faster.

Comment: What I'm currently doing is hosing a MySQL database on a backend server that currently does all of this, and rather efficiently. The problem is the queries are relatively complex and involve several table joins, etc. My initial thought was to somewhat replicate the database setup I have on the backend on a local sqlite database, but before implementing that, I was wondering if there was a faster/better way to do that

Comment: And the reason I want to move away from a backend is because I want to achieve offline data as well as reduce backend server costs. But I like the idea of loading a subset into memory and then sorting

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned, you can't sort by a calculated value with Core Data, so a query for the closest location is unfortunately out. I've used the following "boxing" approach to approximate that, which might or might not meet your needs:

1. Calculate a box around the target location. The offset in degrees is something you'll need to work out, but the Wikipedia article on [decimal degrees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_degrees) can be a good starting point. Offset your target by +/- some number of degrees to get a rough rectangle.
2. Fetch every location within that rectangle.
3. Sort the results in memory to find the closest result.

If you want to make one request for the closest location, you'll probably have to work with SQLite directly. I wouldn't load all of the points into memory without a careful examination of the total memory impact of doing so, and an understanding of how much memory your app is using for other reasons at the same time.